# Binding to UserControl.Resource from within datatemplate created in Code (WPF)

Tags: wpf, vb.net, telerik-grid

I want to reference my datacontext from inside a datatemplate. In XAML it works fine: I create a BindingProxy that is referenced as staticResource from inside the DataTemplate and so I can access the required property.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <helpers:BindingProxy x:Key="DataContextProxy" Data="{Binding}" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <helpers:ComboBoxPerformanceConverter x:Key="AntriebsArtConverter" LookupDictionary="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=Data.AntriebsArtenDict }" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...

    <telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource }">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn                 
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Path=Data.AntriebsArten}"
                DataMemberBinding="{Binding Fahrzeug.AntriebsArtId}"
                SelectedValueMemberPath="AntriebsArtId"
                DisplayMemberPath="Bezeichnung">
                <telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Fahrzeug.AntriebsArtId, Converter={StaticResource AntriebsArtConverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewComboBoxColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
...
```

If I try the same in Code I get everything working except the binding for LookupDictionary. Here I try to reference the datacontext not from the datagrid but from the surrounding UserControl. It gives me the error "Resource with name ""DataContextProxy"" cannot be found. any advice on how I could solve this?

```
Private Function CreateDataTemplate(textblockName As String) As DataTemplate
    Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream
    Dim parserContext As New ParserContext()
    Dim xaml = "<DataTemplate xmlns:helpers=""clr-namespace:ViewModel.Helpers;assembly=ViewModel"">"
    xaml += "<DataTemplate.Resources>"
    xaml += "<helpers:ComboBoxPerformanceConverterVm x:Key=""AntriebsArtConverter""  LookupDictionary=""{Binding Path=Data.AntriebsArtenDict, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}}""/>"
    xaml += "</DataTemplate.Resources><TextBlock Text=""{Binding  Fahrzeug.AntriebsArtId, Converter={StaticResource AntriebsArtConverter}}"" /></DataTemplate>"
    memoryStream = New MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xaml))
    parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation")
    parserContext.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")
    Dim dataTemplate = CType(XamlReader.Load(memoryStream, parserContext), DataTemplate)
    Return dataTemplate
End Function
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In your xaml file, the `helpers:ComboBoxPerformanceConverterVm` is defined outside , its "DataContext" is the UserControl, and knows DataContextProxy.

But in the code, you moved this converter to inside  the DataContext for this converter is now: "Column".

The best solution is to move this converter definition outside of  like what you did in Xaml.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I work with dynamic columns and generate the  combobox so there is no outer object or can I wrap the combobox somehow?